# Can I use difference score as DV and use the baseline score as IV?

Tags: regression, linear

Can I use a difference score as the dependent variable and use the baseline score as the independent variable when doing correlation, linear regression and multivariate linear regression?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking whether you can use the **baseline** score to predict the **difference** in scores? I don't know what type of data and domain you're working with -- but just based on the information you've provided in the question, I don't see any problems in doing this.

Comment: Thank you. yes , I would like to use the baseline score to predict the difference in score. The score is continuous data. actually I am using the functional level score for my patient to predict the improvement of their functional score in the hospital.

Answer (score 1):

If the variables are measured less than perfectly, this is a bad idea because you will be predicting the error of the baseline measure. E.g. suppose person 1 had a "good day" at BL and person B had a "bad day". Then, even if neither changes, it will look like they did.

You should use a multilevel model.

Comment: thank you, yes you are right
What do you mean by multilevel model??

Comment: A multilevel model is one way of analyzing data that is not independent.

Comment: @PeterFlom, but isn't that true for all regression models? We assume that error in measurement is present only in the $y$ but ignore the error in measurement for all $x$'s?

Comment: Not to the same extent.

Comment: Should I still run the multivariate linear regression using the baseline score and other independent that are significant predictors?

Comment: No. You should use a multilevel model

Answer (score 1):

Given you have the same thing measured twice you could either do

```
lm(y2 ~ y1 + x, data = df)
```

or treat it as multilevel/repeated measures to account for the nesting of the two occasions within subjects as @Peter Flom noted)

```
m1 = nlme::lme(y ~ x, random = ~ 1|SID, data = df)
```